# Add whole xml child new element Php

Tags: php, xml, appendchild, getelementsbytagname, createelement

I have this XML file with many child nodes, and I have this PHP code, but this is only adding the first node. I want to add the whole XML in name is node child.

Current XML:

```xml
<root>
<result>
<node>
<someting>asdasd</something>
</node>
<node>
<someting>asdasd</something>
</node>
  </result>
        <error/>
      </root>
```

What I need:

```xml
<root>
<result>
<node>
<someting>asdasd</something>
<Shipping_Cost>9</Shipping_Cost>
</node>
<node>
<someting>asdasd</something>
<Shipping_Cost>9</Shipping_Cost>
</node>
  </result>
        <error/>
      </root>
```

Current PHP code:

```php
function fn_add_shipping($xmlFileToLoad, $destination)
{
    $xmlFileToLoad = 'shipping.xml';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load($xmlFileToLoad);
    $shipping = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node')->item(0);
    $ship = $dom->createElement('Shipping_Cost', '9');
    $shipping->appendChild($ship);
    $dom->save($destination);
    return $destination;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you question is unclear, can you edit it and have another go at explaining what you are trying to do

Comment: its clear now what i need it. Use php function code but it add only first <node> child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I did not realize the 2nd XML file was what you wanted to get as a result of the PHP method. Now that I see that, I think I understand where your problem is. You are only calling the append function one time. You need to loop through each node, calling the append each time before outputting the results to the destination XML file.

Perhaps something like this:

```
function fn_add_shipping($xmlFileToLoad, $destination)
{
    $xmlFileToLoad = 'shipping.xml';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load($xmlFileToLoad);
    $shipping = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node');
    for ($x=0; $x<$shipping->length; $x++)
    {
       $ship = $dom->createElement('Shipping_Cost', '9');
       $shipping[$x]->appendChild($ship);
    }
    $dom->save($destination);
    return $destination;
}
```

Comment: sorry my wrong its inside the node child. :( i change the true code

Comment: gives this error "Stack trace: #0". its a code get error $shipping->appendChild($ship);

Comment: OK. I was just trying to explain that it would need a loop to add to each node. I modified it where I think it will work, but you might need to play with it a bit. Try it again.

Comment: If this has helped you please upvote the answer. And if this solved your issue, please go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thanks!